# DLookUp query to MySql

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I am working on converting a legacy MS access system to a spring-boot application and I came across a big query. I am mostly done with converting the functions from access to mysql but not able to understand how to convert the following DLookUp sub-query as a mySql subquery

```
DLookUp("[price]","tbl_so","[so_id] = " & tbl_trade.so_id & " AND [product_id] = " & tbl_po.product_id
```

What I understood is following won't work as I don't have the Inner Joins set between the 3 tables, `tbl_so`, `tbl_po`, `tbl_trade`

```
SELECT tbl_so.price FROM tbl_so WHERE tbl_so.so_id = tbl_trade.so_id AND tbl_so.product_id = tbl_po.product_id
```

My question is how do I know how the tables will join with each other in this case and also when this DLookUp query is seldom used. And also the solution for this query.

Comment: your mysql will give you an error you have to inner join the tables first. Th efirst join select all the rows from tabl_so that have a partner in the second table and so on. But as long you got both system running. See what access returns and the see what mysql got you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as a general rule, dlookup() can be replaced with a left join. However, you can also use a sub-query and they tend to be "less" change to the query.

So, if we had this:

```
SELECT id, partNum, dlookup("PartDescrt","tblParts","PartID  = " & partNum) 
as Description from tblOrders.
```

You would replace the above dlookup() with a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT id, partNum, 
  (select PartDescrt from tblParts where tblParts.PartID = tblOrders.PartNum)
  AS Description
 from tblOrders
```

The above is SQL or access sql syntax, but quite sure the same should work for MySQL.

If there is more then one partNumber that matches the  above, then add a TOP 1, and a order by with some unique row (PK ID column is best). So the query becomes:

```
  (select TOP 1 PartDescrt from tblParts where tblParts.PartID = tblOrders.PartNum 
     ORDER BY PartDescrt, ID DESC)
  AS Description
```

Comment: another question. what if in your example, the sub query (select PartDescrt from tblParts where tblParts.PartID = tblOrders.PartNum) returns more than 1 rows. I am facing a similar problem now

Comment: see my edit: all you have to do is add a order by some PK row and you only get one.